# Cannot run a project with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload, vendor

I have installed composer globally and when i try the command:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

i got the following exception:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\8gag\app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\8gag\app\autoload.php on line 7
```

Here's the autoload.php file:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

return $loader;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you do composer update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try install **vendors:**

```
composer install
```

Or

```
php composer.phar install
```

Then run:

```
php bin/console server:start
```